# How to call git-fetch from Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I'm developing custom VS extension that will add some more UI to git source control plugin in Visual Studio. The UI is done.

Is there some API in Visual Studio SDK that I can use to invoke git related commands (git fetch for example) or to retrieve git related settings, e.g repository url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call git command through C# code with Process. Please refer to following sample code.

```
string gitCommand = "git";
string gitAddArgument = @"add -A" ;
string gitCommitArgument = @"commit ""explanations_of_changes"" "
string gitPushArgument = @"push our_remote"

Process.Start(gitCommand, gitAddArgument );
Process.Start(gitCommand, gitCommitArgument );
Process.Start(gitCommand, gitPushArgument );
```

And you also could try use LibGit2Sharp NuGet package which is a native Git implementation. About how to use it in C#, please refer to below blog.

http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2015/06/22/getting-information-about-your-git-repository-with-c/

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly this. However, when I install Visual Studio is a git.exe known command? I've always tought that Visual Studio uses some internal git executable by default

Comment: I don't found such fucntions in Visual Studio APIs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt459278.aspx).

Comment: I would like to see source codes of Team Explorer. Any plans to open source it? :)

Comment: You could reflect the Team Explorer installer to check whether you could get the method that it calls. You could get the Team Explorer from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15 and this blog introduce how to reflect a .exe file: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpening/2007/12/19/using-reflection-to-automate-testing-of-an-exe-file/

Comment: The installer probably isn't .NET assembly and it is just setup bootstrapper anyway. Maybe you know in what assembly the Git Source Control extension resides...